# What causes "Generic Error" in php-fpm to be logged in my www-error.log?

Tags: php

I find in my error log (/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log, every-now-and-then, the following gem:

[27-Jun-2022 12:36:39 UTC] Generic Error

I can't find anything on the web discussing "Generic Error" ...

I have recently upgraded the sw stack (AWS Linux 2, with sudo yum update) and I am wondering if something internal to PHP changed in the way it works, and is now throwing this error under some condition.

Since the application is working just fine, I am at a loss. But the error in my log is annoying...

(I don't use any frameworks. The code above PHP libraries is mine, and I do not throw this...)

php-fpm -v:
PHP 7.4.19 (fpm-fcgi) (built: May 13 2021 22:37:56)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

uname -r:
4.14.200-155.322.amzn2.x86_64

cat /etc/os-release:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

Comment: Maybe you use some extension that throws this?

Comment: Maybe try searching for any references, with `grep -R 'Generic' *` in your project root, or `grep -R error_log *`

Comment: I use many php libraries/extensions…  yes, it possibly is one of them. I guess it’s down to good ole debug_log() all over the place until i narrow down what gives. I thought someone may have seen this and save me the brute force hunt…